# Proof that a derived set is closed in a $T_1$-space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a $T_1$-space and $A\subset X$.

Claim: $A'$ is closed, where $A'=\{x\in X|(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A\ne\emptyset$ for all open neighbourhoods of $x\}$.

Proof: Let $x\in (A')^c$ be arbitrary.

Then $x\notin A'$ so there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U\setminus\{x\}\cap A=\emptyset.$

Since $X$ is $T_1,$ it follows that $\{x\}$ is closed and so $U\setminus\{x\}$ is open.

Thus, using the facts that $U\setminus\{x\}\cap A=\emptyset$ and $U\setminus\{x\}$ is open, we have $U\setminus\{x\}\subset (A')^c.$

And since $x\in (A')^c$ it follows that $U\subset (A')^c.$

So we have shown that for any $x\in (A')^c,$ there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U\subset (A')^c,$ and so $(A')^c$ is open.

Does this prove the claim?

EDIT: I know the claim is true. I just wanted to verify whether my reasoning was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is correct. $U \setminus \{x\}$ witnesses not being in $A'$ for all of its members.